# Remove duplication of data in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a column say `TypeOfManager` where there will be entries like

```
TypeOfManager 
-----------------
Sales
Relation
S
R
```

In this case I want to treat 'R' as Relation and 'S' as Sales.

What will be the syntax of the query in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Columna, 
Columnb,
Case when TypeofManager in ('Sales','S') then 'sales'
when TypeofManager in ('Relation','R') then 'Relation'
Else TypeofManager end as TypeOfManager
From yourtable
```

*Columna , columnb* above are to be replaced by whatever real columns you need from your table, obviously.

**Update**

```
Select count(*), typeofmanager, Columna , columnb from (Select Columna, 
Columnb,
Case when TypeofManager in ('Sales','S') then 'sales'
when TypeofManager in ('Relation','R') then 'Relation'
Else TypeofManager end as TypeOfManager
From yourtable ) x
Group by TypeofManager, Columna, columnb
```

Comment: Output Expected
      -------------------------------

      ColumnName       Count
      -----------     --------------
      Sales              2
      Relation           2

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that "S" and "R" can't be changed to "Sales" and "Relation"? If not, just run an update query before you run the main query. If so, then assuming the letters are unique, just do a like "S%" or "R%" query. Or you could write an omni-query that uses Or / And.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a master table to keep manager types

```
Create TypeofManager (
 ManagerTypeId char(1) not null,
 ManagerTypeDescription nvarchar(50)
)
```

Then you can refer to this table from other table data using a foreign key column like `ManagerTypeId`

You can only store `ManagerTypeId` and join two table using `ManagerTypeId` columns